# Подскажите ресурсы где можно найти информацию о передаче файлов через P2P в Android

Tags: android, p2p

Нужно передавать информацию через P2P, а как это делать я пока не нашел. Было бы не плохо если бы кто-нибудь описал механизм или просто дропнул линк на ресурс с инфой.

Comment: P2P можно организовать, например, с помощью Wi-Fi Direct. Есть примеры кода в официальном гайде: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Comment: А также в официальном тренинге: https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

Comment: Там нет информации о том как передавать файлы